# Can not access localhost:port

Tags: asp.net, localhost

I'm using windows 7 32bit and I had developed a asp.net application. 
But when I goto browser on IIS manager or my local address : "localhost:port" by chrome and firefox, receive message: "Website not found". but Internet Explorer still be fine. 
Any one give me some solution?

Comment: To solve this problem please go to; C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\ and open hosts with notepad. You will see a line like below; # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself. # 127.0.0.1 localhost # ::1 localhost Just remove the # before 127.0.0.1                                                            if you still face problem let me know.

Comment: thankyou! but i still face that problem.

Comment: Have you hosted website on IIS?  IF yes then please create application directory now check.otherwise tell me what ever you have done...

Comment: Yes. i hosted website on IIS and Appserv. But, my problem occur in Chrome and FF, in IE not influence